# SSIS Package Duration is big before it begins executing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

hello i have this question.
From Visual Studio i have deployd package in Sql server and i am manualy executing Package.
BUt i have noticed that package need 6 sec to do all things  but Duration is 8 sec Like on pictures so can you tell me what is  this 2 sec?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's hard to predict where those 2 extra seconds are coming from without seeing your SSIS Package and how you're running it. A rough guess is it's some additional runtime that added up from starting the package execution + starting execution of each step. I wouldn't worry much about it unless you start seeing huge discrepancies (but if it's consistently off by a few seconds, then I would lean to what I previously guessed).

According to this StackOverflow, those reports aren't the most accurate way to track and analyze execution times too: [SSIS job taking 'hours' -- All Executions report not adding up or showing errors -- where to find cause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53860487/ssis-job-taking-hours-all-executions-report-not-adding-up-or-showing-errors)

Specifically see Nick.McDermaid's comments:

> Everything you need should be in the logs / reports. No need to run it locally. It's a
> pain, introduces network traffic, is not a true representation and
> doesn't give you much more information. There is a package 'total run
> time' in the top level report (displayed in seconds).

Here are some alternative ways you can track SSIS Package execution times: [Tracking Execution Times for SSIS Packages](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5243/tracking-execution-times-for-ssis-packages/)

Comment: thnx i will try it i have deployd my package too sql server then i connect sql server with ssms and manualy executing package for test